# How to get variables from an object?

Tags: java, object, listadapter

I am creating image_details in a customlistadapter. During this adapter the variable `Answer` is set of each item. Through debugger I'm seeing that I have the data in the place where I need it, but I don't know how to access it:

Debugger image:[image: Debugger]

Here you can see I have 6 questions which each has the variable `int Answer` (open one is set to 0). I want to request the Answer of each item(All 6) when I press save:

```
SaveButton = ((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Save));
SaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Object c = image_details.get(1);
    }
});
```

What should I place in the `onClick` to retrieve this data?

This is my `QuestionItem` class:

```
public class QuestionItem {
    private String Question;
    private String Answer1;
    private String Answer2;
    private String Answer3;
    private String Answer4;
    private int Answer;
    private String[] Answers;

    public String getQuestion() {
        return Question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String Question) {
        this.Question = Question;
    }

    public String Getanswer1() {
        return Answer1;
    }

    public void setAnswer1(String Answer1) {
        this.Answer1 = Answer1;
    }

    public String Getanswer2() {
        return Answer2;
    }

    public void setAnswer2(String Answer2) {
        this.Answer2 = Answer2;
    }

    public String Getanswer3() {
        return Answer3;
    }

    public void setAnswer3(String Answer3) {
        this.Answer3 = Answer3;
    }

    public String Getanswer4() {
        return Answer4;
    }

    public void setAnswer4(String Answer4) {
        this.Answer4 = Answer4;
    }

    public int GetAnswer() {
        return Answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(int Answer) {
        this.Answer = Answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to have the data in the `onClick` method and I suggest you use it in that method.

Comment: how:p if i use image_details.get(0) to get the first question i get the object of question 1 but i cant figure out how to get the data from that object

Comment: You should only access things which you expect to do something useful. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do so I can't suggest how you should do that.  You are accessing a `List` and assuming there is at least 2 values. Not sure you intended to ignore `get(0)`

Answer (score 1):

use instance variables. Heres an example

```
public class Employee{
   // this instance variable is visible for any child class.
  public String name;

// salary  variable is visible in Employee class only.
private double salary;

// The name variable is assigned in the constructor. 
public Employee (String empName){
   name = empName;
}

// The salary variable is assigned a value.
public void setSalary(double empSal){
   salary = empSal;
} 

// This method prints the employee details.
public void printEmp(){
  System.out.println("name  : " + name );
  System.out.println("salary :" + salary);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
   Employee empOne = new Employee("Ransika");
   empOne.setSalary(1000);
  empOne.printEmp();
 } 
}
```